# Is it possible to click an element with phantomJS in protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, protractor

I am trying to click a button while using PhantomJS as my choice of browser, and I am getting many errors.

First attempt, straight clicking a button:

```
var button  = $('#protractorTest');
button.click();
```

Returns the error:

```
Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

Attempting to resize the phantomJS viewport seems to have no effect. The button is at the top left of the screen, but somehow out of the (if I remember correctly) default 400x300 viewport.

```
browser.manage().window().setSize(1920, 1080);
```

I cannot seem to log the window size at any point in time, the closest I can get is an unfinished promise being logged. So, I am unsure if the screensize changes at all.

Searching through lots of other questions, I've tried various execute scripts, different ways to select the element with no success thus far.

Trying to run an execute script to click it, I get issues with undefined is not a function:

```
var hiddenElement = browser.findElement(by.id('protractorTest'));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", hiddenElement).then(function() {
    expect(true).toMatch(true);
});
```

returns this error:

```
Failed: {"errorMessage":"'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'arguments[0].click()')","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"75","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:42837","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java 1.5)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"script\":\"arguments[0].click()\",\"args\":[{\"ELEMENT\":\":wdc:1441214073816\"}]}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/0fa194a0-5196-11e5-a5f1-99fee78af55e/execute"}}
    Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
    System info: host: 'DS5539', ip: '10.4.4.65', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Trying to run the test with a webElement selector returns the same error as above:

```
var hiddenElement = element(by.id('protractorTest')).getWebElement();
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", hiddenElement).then(function() {
    expect(successPage.isDisplayed).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Trying to run the test with a protractor select gives a different error:

```
var hiddenElement = $('#protractorTest');
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", hiddenElement).then(function() {
    expect(successPage.isDisplayed).toBeTruthy();
});

Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Is there any way to click a button using phantomJS and protractor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you choose PhantomJS as your target browser, I bet you'll come back to SO with a new problem in the nearest future. Even `protractor` developers [recommend against it](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6ebc4c3f8b557a56e53e0a1622d1b44b59f5bc04/docs/browser-setup.md#setting-up-phantomjs):

> We recommend against using PhantomJS for tests with Protractor. There
>   are many reported issues with PhantomJS crashing and behaving
>   differently from real browsers.

Plus, if you are doing this for testing, you should have your test environment be as close to the end user's environment as possible - have you seen the users of your application using `PhantomJS`? - probably not.

If you are picking up `PhantomJS` because of it's headless nature and absence of a real display, you might run firefox or chrome in a headless mode too, see:

- [protractor with any headless browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360592/protractor-with-any-headless-browser)
- [What is a good headless browser to run with protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266167/what-is-a-good-headless-browser-to-run-with-protractor)

Also, read this [@Louis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332608/not-sure-why-use-headless-browser/32337373#comment52549451_32337373) - great essay on headless vs headful.

Or, you can use remote selenium servers at [`BrowserStack` or `Sauce Labs` or similar services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29266649/771848).

---

The latest approach you've taken has a problem - `isDisplayed` should be called:

```
var hiddenElement = $('#protractorTest');
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", hiddenElement).then(function() {
    expect(successPage.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    //                        HERE^
});
```

Or/And, you may scroll into view of an element with [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

```
var button  = $('#protractorTest');
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button.getWebElement()).then(function () {
    button.click();
});
```

Adding an [explicit wait](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) might also help:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(button), 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I realize PhantomJS isn't recommended, I am being tasked with proving if it can or cannot work for our needs - automated tests running in TeamCity. This is pushing me away from it being viable for sure!

My mistake on the isDisplayed call there, that was just a quick example I whipped up. For these tests, I have been using presenceOf and checking for innerHtml values(getText needs the element to be visible as well).

Scrolling the element into view has the same issues as clicking - funnily enough even having the not visible/manipulable error.

Comment: Thank you for the links for research. We will be setting up a BrowserStack environment soon, this was just in hopes to work nicely with TeamCity. I will take a look at the other headless browsers as well.